# Finding a density function that maximizes an integral

Tags: optimization, density-function, integral-equations, optimal-control

I have the following maximization problem originating in stochastic control theory. However, I shall present it as a general optimization problem.

For a $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ (may as well consider $U = \mathbb{R}$) let us denote by $\mathcal{P}(U)$ the set of all density functions on $U,$ that may also depend on $x \in \mathbb{R}.$ That is $\int_U \pi(x,u) du = 1$ and $\pi(x,u) \geq 0$ for each $x$ and $u.$ We are looking for a density $\pi(x,u)$ such that it maximizes the integral
\begin{equation}
\int_U \big(h(x,u) - \lambda \ln(\pi(x,u)) \big) \pi(x,u) du,
\end{equation}

for some function $h(x,u)$ for which the only restraint is that all the integrals are finite.

The paper I am studying says that the optimal $\pi^*(x,u)$ is of the form

\begin{align}
\pi^*(x,u) = \frac{\exp{(\frac{1}{\lambda}h(x,u))}}{\int_U \exp{(\frac{1}{\lambda}h(x,u))} du}.
\end{align}

There is no other explanation in the paper. I could figure out that if we insert the optimal density in the integral and denote $K(x) = \int_U \exp{(\frac{1}{\lambda}h(x,u))} du$ we get that the integral equals to $\lambda \ln(K(x)),$ so we get rid of $h(x,u)$ although it still hides in $K(x)$ indirectly. But I can't see why is it so obvious that this is the maximal possible value of this integral. What am I missing? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I was thinking some more. Is it perhaps the case that if we want to find a maximum of this integral for all functions $h$ the only way is to get rid of it in some sense. Otherwise, for any $\pi$ one could find an $h$ such that the maximizing integral would be larger. And then since the $\pi$ has to be a density this is the only meanigful way to write it. Am I thinking in the right direction?

Comment: The integral is a functional in $\pi$ :$J[\pi]=\int_U(h(x,u)-\lambda\ln(\pi(x,u)))\pi(x,u)du$. The solution shall be extremal forall variation $f(x,u)$ hence $\frac{dJ[\pi^*+\epsilon f]}{d\epsilon}|_{\epsilon=0}=0$. This gives you an equation for $\pi^*$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.